# Checking if X can be normal height based on sample of 100 elements

Tags: statistics

I have a sample of 120 different heights (between 80 and 100). I have to check if the normal average height is i.e. 86. So I'm creating a hypothesis that the hypothetical mean is 86 or alternative hypothesis saying it's not.

I performed the t-test in minitab software to perform the calculations. It calculated the mean of the sample (that is, it calculated arithmetic mean of the 120 elements), it calculated standard dev. (I don't know how) and it showed confidence interval on 95% confidence level. the p-value was 0.000

I assume that it's not really 0 but something like 0.00...001, correct? It would suggest that there is almost no chance that the mean of whole population would be 86?

Second question is how was the standard dev calculated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Minitab, a P-value reported as `0.000` means $< 0.0005.$
In other words, the null hypothesis is rejected at any
reasonable level of significance.

Heights of $what$ and in what units? If it's humans in inches
 then they must be very tall ones, even for
basketball players: 6'9" to 8'3".

This would be a lot easier to answer if you had told me
what mean and standard deviation Minitab found. In the
absence of that information, I'll speculate.

Judging by the range of the data and by "typical" ratios between
heights and standard deviations, you $might$ have a sample
standard deviation around 3.5 or 4 units. So maybe
Minitab found the sample standard deviation to be around
$S = 3.5$ Then the standard error of the mean `SE MEAN` would be 
$S/\sqrt{120} = 0.32.$ In that case, if the $sample\; mean$ differed
from the hypothetical mean $86$ by more than 0.64, then you'd reject the null hypothesis.

Minitab uses the standard formula to find sample standard deviation.
$$S = \sqrt{\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \bar X)^2}{n-1}},$$
where $n$ is the sample size and $\bar X$ is the sample mean.

A consulting statistician I know has a framed saying on his wall,
``68.35% of all statistics are made up on the spot.'' Why am
I reminded of that just now, I wonder?

Comment: Sorry for not providing specific details, still your answer was more than perfect and what's more important it helped me to search the information on the Internet once I knew what I should be searching for.